# Sort blocks of TR with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablesorter

Using TableSorter plugin, i need to sort multiple TR who are a block composed by multiple TR (undefined number of sub TR) (example in jsfiddle)

```
<tbody id='ligne-pilote'>
    <tr data-id='4578575' class='lineX'>
        <td colspan='10' class='group-tr'>
            <table class='line'>
                <tr height='26'>
                    <td class='b-right' width='33%'>Arbre</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'><span>250</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'><span>360</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>5</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>35</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>72</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>1200</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'>3850</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='15%' align='center'>2055</td>
                    <td class='' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Pin blanc</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%'align='center'>Sub-Data-col 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Saules</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%'align='center'>Sub-Data-col 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id='45784515' class='lineX'>
        <td colspan='10' class='group-tr'>
            <table class='line'>
                <tr height='26' >
                    <td class='b-right' width='33%'>Bateau</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'><span>3520</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'><span>6230</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>321</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>322</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>323</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='8%' align='center'>500</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='6%' align='center'>780</td>
                    <td class='b-right' width='15%' align='center'>6542</td>
                    <td width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Royal Fortune</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col2 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col2 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col2 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Royal James</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- The Ranger</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='26' class='test'>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='33%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- Queen Anne's Revenge</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 2</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'><span>Sub-Data-col3 3</span></td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 4</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 5</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 6</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='8%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 7</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='6%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 8</td>
                    <td class='b-right b-top' width='15%' align='center'>Sub-Data-col3 9</td>
                    <td class='b-top' width='2%' align='center'>ok</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gratien/mn3gpu2h/10/

When I click on "Col1" i need to sort only the first line of each block of this column, same thing with "Col 2" who must sort only the second column.

I don't know how to make this, can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good case for the [`sort-tbodies` widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-tbodies.html) (see the [last example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-tbodies.html#table4)).

**[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mn3gpu2h/30/)**

You'll need to reformat the HTML... remove the `td` with a `colspan`, `table` and first `tr` of each block:

```
  <td colspan='10' class='group-tr'>
    <table class='line'>
      <tr height='26' >
```

and the associated closing tags

```
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
```

then wrap each block in a `<tbody>...</tbody>`:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="lineX">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

And lastly, initialize tablesorter on the outer table:

```
$("#sort").tablesorter({ 
  sortList: [0,0],
  sortMultiSortKey: 'altKey',
  widgets: ['sortTbody'],
  widgetOptions: {
    sortTbody_lockHead: true,
    sortTbody_primaryRow: '.lineX',
    sortTbody_sortRows: true
  }
});
```

Don't forget to include the `widget-sortTbodies` widget:

```
<script src="../js/widgets/widget-sortTbodies.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hooooooly sh***t, i didn't see this little link, a thousand thanks :D